# Default thread-safe data structure ( by default not making it thread-safe)

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, thread-safety

I'm learning about multithreading and I came up to the point to see if there's any thread-safe data structure by default, I looked on the internet and I found only one statement.

```
immutable is thread-safe.
```

but actually, I'm looking for a general question, like is the tree/stack/graph/linked-list...etc is thread-safe by default?

another question does the immutable are different from language to language? I mean for example string is immutable in Java, but does that mean it might be mutable in C/C++ for example?

**Before closing my question**, just let me be clear, I know how to make any data structure thread-safe, but I'm asking if there's any **by default** a thread-safe

Comment: "I know how to make any data structure thread-safe" - that's an overreaching statement. There are plenty of data structures that are inherently unsafe. It is not possible to make them thread-safe without making substantive changes - and then you're really making a new data structure.

Comment: Also the concept of "thread-safe by default" is a little tricky. If you can write thread-safe components it is possible to combine them in such a way to make your program non-thread-safe.

Comment: the idea about my question is to find if there are any default data structures, so I said I can change any data structure because this is the third time I open a question about the same topic and they close it and telling me that it's already answered which will be a question "how to change tree or array to be thread-safe".

Comment: I understand the idea behind your question. If this has been closed twice already you should probably learn from that and ask the question differently. Have you read [ask]?

Comment: yes, and this question is not closed because I asked it in a different way.

Comment: It has also not been answered yet. Good questions get answered very quickly here. You may need to work on it some more.